# angular 6 jquery plugin not working with dynamic data

Tags: jquery, angular

Good Day to everyone.
I am new to angular and I am trying to add a jquery plugin (ubislider with elevatezoom) for my angular 6 ecommerce project. The plugin works fine with static image urls. But when I try to loop through the list with dynamically generated array of images using http service, the plugin fails.
I tried with various solutions I found on the internet but nothing worked.
Kindly help me fixing this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following is the script code I used for the initialization of plugin in ngAfterViewInit(). `code`     $('#slider2').ubislider({
      arrowsToggle: true,
      type: 'ecommerce',
      hideArrows: true,
      autoSlideOnLastClick: true,
      modalOnClick: true,
      position: 'vertical',
      onTopImageChange: function() {
        $('#imageSlider img').elevateZoom();
      }

Comment: give details on the failure, also edit your post to provide the code sample